# Working with the Royal Mail PAF file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been given the depressing task of trying to do something with the Royal Mail PAF file that we have just bought, I have now loaded all the relevant tables in to our SQL server and linked them together based on relevant ID's.  What I now need to do is put together proper address's based on there multiple rules, e.g. If only Building Name or Number is supplied or if a PO Box is supplied when given a specific post code.  I was hoping that as this seems to be a wildly used file someone might have done some of the work on this, anyone any ideas as they are wanting it by the end of the week.

Hope someone can help, P

Comment: Is that the one that has PAO_START_NO, PAO_START_SFX, PAO_END_NO, PAO_END_SFX, PAO_DESC, SAO_START_NO, etc....?

Comment: This isn't an answer I know, but I suspect it might just as well be one. Yes, we've done something with PAF. It was done at my company though and I can't therefore post it. As PAF is expensive I'd be surprised if anyone could...

Comment: Hi and thanks for all the replies, SeanW I am not quiet sure what PAO_START_NO etc is as I don't remember any of my files having those names or containing anything like that within them.

Comment: Hi Ben,  to be honest I thought that might of been the case, I don't really understand why the Royal Mail makes it so difficult, we have purchased all their data at considerable cost but you would of thought they would give us a break and show us how to put it together in a decent format :-)

Answer (score 0):

Be depressed - thats one big job - lots of rules many exceptions.
I take it you've seen all the rules in the PAF programmers guide ? http://www.royalmail.com/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/programmers_guide_edition_7_v5.pdf
If you want it done by end of week you would be better off getting the "Compressed Standard" version which is in fact the expanded addresses that you are after but of course it is not normalised for a database.
I did the build of addresses from the relational format a long while back. I'll see if I can find the code.

Found some ugly 8 year old Perl - use with caution

```
    while ( <PAF> )  # Reading from mysql view - you can work this out from the fields populated by the split /\t/
    {
      chomp;
      $incount++;
      print STDERR "Processed ..... $incount\n" if $incount%1000000 == 0;

      my ( $postcode       , $aKey           , $lkey        , $skey         , 
           $sekey          , $dskey          , $dsekey      , $bnumber      ,
           $bkey           , $sbkey          , $households  , $oKey         ,
           $fmtPcType      , $concat         , $dps         , $fmtsUser     ,
           $poBox          , $version        , $active      , 
           $fmtCompany     , $fmtDepartment  , $rawSubLine  , $rawBldLine   , 
           $DepSteet       , $fmtDepSteetEnd , $Steet       , $fmtSteetEnd  , 
           $DepLocality    , $Locality       , $PostTown )
           = split /\t/ , $_ , -1 ;

      my $fmtaKey  = sprintf("%08s",$aKey);
      my $fmtoKey  = sprintf("%08s",$oKey);

      $fmtoKey = "" if $fmtoKey eq "00000000" ;
      $fmtoKey = $fmtaKey if $fmtPcType eq "L"; 

      $fmtDepLocality       = removePunch($DepLocality);
      $fmtLocality          = removePunch($Locality,"dq");
      $fmtDepSteet          = removePunch($DepSteet);
      $fmtSteet             = removePunch($Steet,"dh");
      $rawSubLine           = removePunch($rawSubLine,"d");
      $rawBldLine           = removePunch($rawBldLine,"d");
      my $fmtPostTown       = removePunch($PostTown);

      my ($opc,$ipc) = unpack("A4A3" ,$postcode);

      $opc =~ s/\s$//;

      my $fmtPoBox      = "PO BOX $poBox"  if (length($poBox) > 0);  

      my ($fmtSubBuilding , $fmtBuilding ) = ( "","") ;

      # ##############################################################################
      # Format rules are based on presence of builing name , subbuilding and number
      # See PAF Digest for details
      # ##############################################################################

      my ($subBuildingFlag,$buildingFlag,$buildingNumberFlag) = ("N","N","N") ;

      $buildingNumberFlag ="Y" if $bnumber ne "0" ;
      $buildingFlag       ="Y" if length($rawBldLine) > 0;
      $subBuildingFlag    ="Y" if length($rawSubLine) > 0;

      my $formatKey="${subBuildingFlag}${buildingFlag}${buildingNumberFlag}";
      my $ruleid ;
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 1 (Org name only)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      if ( $formatKey eq "NNN" )
      {
          $ruleid="1";
      }

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 2 (Building number only)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      elsif ( $formatKey eq "NNY" )
      {
        $ruleid="2";

        InsertNumber ($bnumber) ;
      }

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 3 (Building Name only)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      elsif ($formatKey eq "NYN")
      {
        $ruleid="3";
        my $N="";

        ($fmtBuilding,$N) = split /\|/ , F1Check ($rawBldLine) , -1 ;

        InsertNumber ($N) ;
      }

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 4 (Building Name and building Number)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      elsif ($formatKey eq "NYY")
      {
        $ruleid="4";
        $fmtBuilding  = "$rawBldLine";
        InsertNumber ($bnumber) ;
      }

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 5 (SubBuilding Name and building Number)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      elsif ($formatKey eq "YNY")
      {
        $ruleid="5";

        if ($concat eq "Y")
        {
          my $numSub  = "$bnumber $rawSubLine";
          InsertNumber ($numSub) ;
        }
        else
        {
          $fmtSubBuilding = "$rawSubLine";
          InsertNumber ($bnumber) ;
        }

      }

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 6 (SubBuilding Name and building name)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      elsif ($formatKey eq "YYN" )
      {

         $ruleid="6";
        ($fmtSubBuilding,$N1) = split /\|/ , F1Check ($rawSubLine) , -1 ;
        ($fmtBuilding,$N2) = split /\|/ , F1Check ($rawBldLine) , -1 ;

        if ( $fmtSubBuilding eq "" )
        {
          if ( $N2 =~ /^REAR OF/ )
          {
            $fmtSubBuilding .= "$N1 $N2" ;
            $N1 = "" ;
            $N2 = "" ;
          }
          else
          {
            $fmtSubBuilding .= "$N1 " . $fmtBuilding;
            $fmtBuilding = "";
            $N1 = "" ;
          }
        }

        $N2 = $N1 if $N2 eq "";
        InsertNumber ($N2) ;
      }

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Formmating Rule 7 (SubBuilding Name ,building name and building number)
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      elsif ($formatKey eq "YYY" )
      {
        $ruleid="7";
        ($fmtSubBuilding,$N1) = split /\|/ , F1Check ($rawSubLine) , -1 ;
        ($fmtBuilding,$N2) = split /\|/ , F1Check ($rawBldLine) , -1 ;

        if ( $fmtSubBuilding eq "" )
        {
          $fmtSubBuilding .= "$N1 " . $fmtBuilding;
          $fmtBuilding = "";
        }

        InsertNumber ($bnumber) ;
      }


      # ##############################################################################
      # Format the address
      # ##############################################################################

      #----------------------------------------------------------------
      # subbuilding = building if no subbuilding (why?)
      #----------------------------------------------------------------

      if (( length($fmtBuilding) > 0) &&  ($fmtSubBuilding eq "" ))
      {
        $fmtSubBuilding = $fmtBuilding;
        $fmtBuilding = "";
      }

      #----------------------------------------------------------------
      # Get rid of duplicate lines
      #----------------------------------------------------------------

      if ("${fmtSubBuilding}${fmtBuilding}" eq "${fmtSteet}${fmtSteetEnd}") 
      {
        $fmtSubBuilding="";
        $fmtBuilding=""; 
      }

      #----------------------------------------------------------------
      # Parse out number ranges (including number suffixes)
      #----------------------------------------------------------------  

      my ($fmtStreetName ,$lo_num , $low_suf , $hi_num ,$hi_suf) = split /\|/ ,  getLoHiNum ("$fmtSteet") , -1 ;
      my $dependentTfare = "$fmtDepSteet";
      $dependentTfare .= " $fmtDepSteetEnd" if length($fmtDepSteetEnd) > 0;


    # ABERDEEN CITY COUNCIL|EDUCATION DEPARTMENT||ST NICHOLAS HOUSE||||BROAD|STREET|||ABERDEEN|ABERDEENSHIRE|AB10|1AG|1A|0|01901355|01901355|L||

     my $fmtaddr .=  "$postcode|$dps|$fmtaKey|$fmtoKey|$fmtPoBox|$fmtSubBuilding|$fmtBuilding|$fmtDepSteet|$fmtDepSteetEnd|" ;
        $fmtaddr .=  "$fmtSteet|$fmtSteetEnd|$fmtDepLocality|$fmtLocality|$fmtPostTown|$opc|$ipc|"  ;
        $fmtaddr .=  "$ruleid|$lo_num|$low_suf|$hi_num|$hi_suf|$dependentTfare|$fmtStreetName";

     print "$fmtaddr\n";
    }

    close PAF;

    # # ############################################################################
    # SUB F1Check (PAF Digest Note:1 Page 42)
    #
    # Try and extract a number embeded in the (sub)building name
    # There are loads of exceptions to the rules in the PAF digest
    # hence the horrible regex's
    # # ############################################################################

    sub F1Check
    {

      my ($building) = (@_);

      my $bnumber = "";

     if ($building =~ m/^REAR OF.+\d/ )
     {
        $bnumber=$building;
        $building="" ;
     }

     elsif (($building =~ m/\d+/) && ($building !~ /UNIT[S]?\s|
                                                  FLAT[S]?\s|
                                                  ^DP\d+[A-Z]?$|
                                                  BLOCK[S]?\s|
                                                  ^OFFICE[S]?\s|
                                                  HANG[EA]R\s|
                                                  ^BUILDING[S]?\s|
                                                  ^HOUSE\s|
                                                  HOLDING\s|
                                                  APARTMENT\s|
                                                  CHALET\s|
                                                  ^BUNGALOW\s|
                                                  ^CARAVAN\s|
                                                  ^ANNEXE\s|
                                                  ^PLOT[S]?\s|
                                                  ^HOME[S]?\s|
                                                  ^LODGE\s\d|
                                                  ^PLATFORM\s|
                                                  ^DOMUS\s|
                                                  ^BARLOW\s|
                                                  ^BEALAH\s|
                                                  ^KIOSK[S]?\s|
                                                  ^LEVEL[S]?\s|
                                                  ^VILLA\s|
                                                  MEOTA\s|
                                                  MAXI[NM]\s|
                                                  ^AQUEOUS\s|
                                                  SUITE[S]?\s|
                                                  WING\s|
                                                  ^CAMPUS\s|
                                                  ^STUDIO\s|
                                                  ^COTTAGE\s|
                                                  ^STALL\s|
                                                  ^SHOP\s|
                                                  ^ARCH\s|
                                                  ^QUAY\s|
                                                  ^ABOVE\s\d|
                                                  ^LINK\s|
                                                  JETTY\s|
                                                  WAREHOUSE\s|
                                                  ^HOLDING\s|
                                                  ^PENTHOUSE\s|
                                                  ^MOORING\s|
                                                  ^BOTHY\s|
                                                  ^MAISONETTE\s|
                                                  ^SITE\s|
                                                  ^WORKSHOP\s|
                                                  ^BARN[S]?\s|
                                                  STALL\s|
                                                  ^BOAT\s|
                                                  ^STAND\s|
                                                  ^TOWER\s\d|
                                                  ^YARD\s\d|
                                                  ^STANCE\s|
                                                  ^VAN\s|
                                                  ^BAY\s\d|
                                                  ^MOBILE HOME\s|
                                                  ^STABLE\s|
                                                  ^ROOM\s|
                                                  ^[A-Z]\d+$
                                                  /xo
                                                  ))
      {

        if  ( $building =~ m/^([A-Z]?\d+[A-Z]{0,2}|
                            \d+[A-Z]{0,2}[\-\&\ \\\/]{0,1}\d+[A-Z]{0,2}|
                            [A-Z])$/ox )
        {
          $bnumber=$building;
          $building="" ;
        }
        elsif  ($building =~ m/^([A-Z]?\d*\s*[A-Z\s\.]+)(\d+[A-Z]{0,2}[\-\&\ \\\/]{0,1}\d*[A-Z]{0,2})$/o)
        {
          if (length($1) > 2)
          {
            $bnumber=$2;
            $building=$1;
            $building =~ s/\s+$//g;
          }
        }
       elsif   ($building =~ m/^(\D+)(\d+[A-Z]{0,2}[\-\&\ \\\/]\d+[A-Z]{0,2})$/)
       {
        $bnumber=$2;
        $building=$1;
        $building =~ s/\s+$//g;
       }  
     }   
     return "$building|$bnumber"
    }

    # # ############################################################################
    # SUB InsertNumber
    #
    # Prepend number to first non blank line from thoroughfare onwards
    # # ############################################################################

    sub InsertNumber
    {
        my ($N) = (@_) ;

        if ( $N =~ /\d/  && $N ne "0")
        {
          if    (length($fmtDepSteet)     > 0)  {$fmtDepSteet    = $N . " " . $fmtDepSteet ;}
          elsif (length($fmtSteet)  > 0)  {$fmtSteet  = $N . " " . $fmtSteet;}
          elsif (length($fmtDepLocality)    > 0)  {$fmtDepLocality    = $N . " " . $fmtDepLocality ;}
          else                              {$fmtLocality     = $N . " " . $fmtLocality;} ;
        }
    }

    # # ############################################################################
    # SUB getLoHiNum
    #
    # Extract number ranges 
    # # ############################################################################

    sub getLoHiNum
    {

      my ($tfare) = (@_) ;

      my ($lonum,$losuf,$hinum,$hisuf) = ( "","","","");

    # extract numbers and suffixes  
      my ($num,$tt) = ($tfare=~ /^(\d+[A-Z]?[\-]?\d*[A-Z]?)\s(.*)$/ );

      if (length($num) > 0)
      {
        $tfare = $tt ;
        if ( $num =~ m/[\-]{1}/ ) 
        {
          ($lonum,$hinum) = ($num=~ /(\d+.*)[\-](\d+.*)/ ); 
        }
        else
        {
          $lonum = $num;
        }

        if ( $lonum =~ m/[A-Z]$/ ) 
        {
          ($lonum,$losuf) = ($lonum=~ /(\d+)([A-Z])$/ ); 
        }

        if ( $hinum =~ m/[A-Z]$/ ) 
        {
          ($hinum,$hisuf) = ($hinum=~ /(\d+)([A-Z])$/ ); 
      }
      }
      return "$tfare|$lonum|$losuf|$hinum|$hisuf" ;
    }


    # # ############################################################################
    # SUB removePunch
    #
    # Remove punchuation
    # # ############################################################################

    sub removePunch
    {

      my ($dirtyWord,$punch) = (@_) ;
      $punch = "dhqa" if length($punch) == 0;

      $dirtyWord =~ s/\.//g     if $punch =~ m/d/ ;
      $dirtyWord =~ s/\-/ /g    if $punch =~ m/h/ ;
      $dirtyWord =~ s/\'//g     if $punch =~ m/q/ ;
      $dirtyWord =~ s/\@//g     if $punch =~ m/a/ ;

      return $dirtyWord;
    }
```

Comment: Hi LimeGreen, thanks for the help and the code example, even though in Perl its basically what I thought I might have to do...and yes I have read all of the programmers guide and all the rules and I didn't have much hair before hand I am going to have even less at the end of this.  If you do have any code even if not complete that would be great but going to make a start in the morning and see how I get on....thanks again to everyone who has replied, all help is much appreciated. P

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this issue, if I understand the question correctly, to re-construct the address from the data files, the columns in the RM PAF files are in reverse order. So to build a simple address string, checking columns right to left, you just check each one for a value, and if it has one, concatenate it in to your address string with a space. If you look at some examples that use each of the fields, you can work out the parsing for spaces and commas.